# QGIS Server 2.12.14 Errors with Oracle

Tags: oracle-spatial, qgis-server, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012

We are using QGIS Server to serve Oracle SPatial (11.2.0.4) to a spatial viewer. There is 16Gb of RAM. The number of concurrent users is 100-150.

QGIS Server is on Windows Server 2012 R2 with 16GB of RAM. Oracle is on Windows Server 2008 R2 with 8Gb of RAM.

We are having intermittent issues with the stability of QGIS Server.

Is anyone else using QGIS Server and Oracle Spatial and experiencing similar problems?
Error from Oracle log:

```
Thu Jul 14 08:18:46 2016
Errors in file E:\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\gisp\gisp\trace\gisp_ora_7876.trc  (incident=467230):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kghssgfr2], [12], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-12571: TNS:packet writer failure
ORA-12571: TNS:packet writer failure
Incident details in: E:\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\gisp\gisp\incident\incdir_467230\gisp_ora_7876_i467230.trc
Thu Jul 14 08:18:58 2016
Errors in file E:\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\gisp\gisp\trace\gisp_ora_10724.trc  (incident=466160):
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kghssgfr2], [4], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
ORA-03135: connection lost contact
ORA-03135: connection lost contact
Incident details in: E:\ORACLE\diag\rdbms\gisp\gisp\incident\incdir_466160\gisp_ora_10724_i466160.trc
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
opidcl aborting process unknown ospid (10724) as a result of ORA-600
Thu Jul 14 08:19:01 2016
Dumping diagnostic data in directory=[cdmp_20160714081901], requested by (instance=1, osid=10724), summary=[incident=466160].
Thu Jul 14 08:19:05 2016
Sweep [inc][467230]: completed
Sweep [inc][466160]: completed
Sweep [inc2][466160]: completed
Thu Jul 14 08:19:13 2016
Use ADRCI or Support Workbench to package the incident.
See Note 411.1 at My Oracle Support for error and packaging details.
opidcl aborting process unknown ospid (7876) as a result of ORA-600
Thu Jul 14 08:20:05 2016
Sweep [inc2][467230]: completed
```

QGIS Server error from log:

```
[Mon Jul 18 10:10:44 2016] [warn] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_fcgid: read timeout from pipe
[Mon Jul 18 10:10:44 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe
[Mon Jul 18 10:10:51 2016] [warn] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_fcgid: read timeout from pipe
[Mon Jul 18 10:10:51 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe
[Mon Jul 18 10:14:58 2016] [warn] [client 127.0.0.1] (OS 109)The pipe has been ended.  : mod_fcgid: get overlap result error
[Mon Jul 18 10:14:58 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe </blink>
```

Comment: Please always place error messages in the body of the question as TEXT (ASCII).  There are two reasons: 1) It's legible on any device 2) Anyone with the same error will be able to find your question (and its answer).  As a new user, please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour)

Comment: Do you get errors from the database ? If so, what are those errors ? As Vince said, always show the full errors as plain text. Also I assume QGIS keeps a full log of what it does with all exceptions it encounters. Are the 16GB of RAM for the server that runs QGIS ? How about the config of the server that runs the database ?

Comment: Sorry about the formatting.<br/> QGIS Server is on Windows Server 2012 R2 with 16GB of RAM. Oracle is on Windows Server 2008 R2 with 8Gb of RAM. <br/>

Comment: Can anyone assist with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a very old post but, for what it worth, we get the same with SpatialNet which uses Oracle GIS basic package. Ours is an old 11.2.0.4 DB on Linux. I did some research in My Oracle Support and I think this is the problem,

ORA-600 [kghssgfr2] After ORA-12571 (Doc ID 2026790.1)

The conclusion is that network problems cause the DB connection to drop which in turn causes the internal unhandled exception (ORA-600). IDK, I think if that's the case then the exception shouldn't be unhandled and they should report a more informative error message. In any case, here is a workaround proposed in that MOS note,

SOLUTION
Ideally avoid/resolve the network errors. Still, if they occur, given there is no actual bug fix, you can set next parameters at the same time as a workaround:

"_optimizer_extended_cursor_sharing"='NONE'

"_optimizer_extended_cursor_sharing_rel"='NONE'

Whatever else those two could do, only Oracle knows.